# How to go back to my old setup

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery

I am new to Ubuntu. Just now I recovered my ubuntu 12.04 laptop. All files are there and all application are there at **`/opt`** folder. But I dont know how to run those applications. Sound drivers are also not working. Please tell me how to get back to my system as before.

Comment: which applications are there in /opt?

Comment: eclispse..sublimetext..google browser etc. I installed so many appplications...how to get back those app back with out installing again and again...

Comment: You will find google chrome in Unity Search. I mean just press your 'start' button & type 'chrome'. Comment here if you didnt get it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Ubuntu Software Center` > type `Ubuntu restricted extras` > `Install` then restart your pc. Your sound drivers should surely work!

Type this in terminal make your softwares working.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/local/bin/eclipse
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/eclipse/eclipse
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/local/bin/eclipse
sudo chmod -R u+rw,go+x /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Now this command should open your eclipse:

```
eclipse
```

or else make shortcut in dash Unity by typing this in terminal

```
cd ~/Desktop
touch eclipse.desktop
gedit eclipse.desktop
```

An empty file will open, copy this text & Paste in that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save it then type this in terminal:

```
 sudo cp ~/Desktop/eclipse.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

Same applies to your other software in `/opt` folder.

Comment: Showing error..Cannot exe binary file..

Comment: execute this command in terminal sudo chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse

Comment: i did that one...

Comment: can you copy paste full error from terminal & at which command you are getting this error?

Comment: username@username:~$eclispe
bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse: cannot execute binary file

Comment: type this 'sudo chown -R username:username /opt/eclipse' REMEMBER REPLACE YOUR USERNAME in place of username without quotes & reply

Comment: ya my username is there....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14207/discussion-between-dpn-and-bhr)

Comment: sudo chmod -R u+rw+x /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse